# How to Convert a CCSprite image to UIImage?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uiimage, ccsprite

As the title, I have mentioned the code below

```
CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)node;
CCTexture2D *texture2d = [sprite texture];
```

How can I get a UIImage *p from sprite?

Answer (score 6):

In your case just add next methood into your class:

```
 - (UIImage *) imageFromSprite :(CCSprite *)sprite
{
    int tx = sprite.contentSize.width;
    int ty = sprite.contentSize.height;

    CCRenderTexture *renderer   = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:tx height:ty];

    sprite.anchorPoint  = CGPointZero;

    [renderer begin];
    [sprite visit];
    [renderer end];

    return [renderer getUIImage];
}
```

how to use:

```
CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)node;
UIImage *p = [self imageFromSprite:sprite]
```

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong but the image gets pretty misplaced using this.

Comment: You're changing the anchorPoint before rendering. Need to change it back to its original value later.

Answer (score 4):

uhh...

I think this is a better to way. Add this as a category on CCNode.

```
-(UIImage*)image {
    CCRenderTexture* renderer = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:self.contentSize.width height:self.contentSize.height];

    const CGPoint ANCHORBEFORE = self.anchorPoint;
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;

    [renderer begin];
    [self visit];
    [renderer end];
    self.anchorPoint = ANCHORBEFORE;

    return [renderer getUIImage];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using cocos2d 2.x, render sprite into CCRenderTexture and call getUIImage method of that render texture.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the source code of both CCSprite and CCTexture2D you can see that the image is used only for creating the texture data and the image object is not kept but temporarily used.

**CCTexture2D** source :

http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/source/browse/trunk/cocos2d/CCTexture2D.m?r=1882

**CCSprite** source :

http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/source/browse/trunk/cocos2d/CCSprite.m?r=1747

Look in the init methods that use CGImageRef