# Can I generate .png files from my cocos2d-iphone application in the simulator?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator

Given a cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1 game running in the simulator, is it possible to save a `CCTexture2D` instance as a .png file in my Mac? Similarly to the way you can create .plist files by using the `writeToFile` method of a dictionary (when you do it in the simulator, the file is created in the simulator's support folder in the Mac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple, first create CCSprite from CCTexture2d then CCSprite to UIImage. Here is link that helps to create UIImage from CCSprite: [How to Convert a CCSprite image to UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136206/how-to-convert-a-ccsprite-image-to-uiimage)

Then call writeToFile on UIImage.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/save-uiimage-object-as-a-png-or-jpeg-file.html

Comment: Didn't even think of UIImage. Thanks!